# how to set the checkbox of a checkboxtree to be disabled?

Tags: java, editor, render, jtree, jcheckbox

I used this checkboxtree: [it.cnr.imaa.essi.lablib.gui.checkboxtree](http://www.essi-lab.eu/projectsSites/lablib-checkboxtree/apidocs/it/cnr/imaa/essi/lablib/gui/checkboxtree/package-summary.html), and this is the introduction: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-checkboxtree.html?page=1.

But when I add treenode, I want to set some of the treenodes to be disabled. What api can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `TreeCheckingModel` interface, one of the methods is `setPathEnabled`.

You would `setPathEnabled(treePath, false)` to disable the `TreePath`.

Comment: but how can I get the treepath when I am building the checkboxtree?

Comment: ummm, I think I know how to do that. Thanks!